# How to find group of three elements in array whose sum equals to target sum?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can do this with three loops but complexity will be O(n3), can it be done with less complexity?

Adding js fiddle code for three loops approach

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var sum = 8;
find(arr, sum);

function find(arr, sum) {
  var found = false;
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length - 3; x++) {
    for (var y = x + 1; y < arr.length - 2; y++) {
      for (var z = y + 1; z < arr.length; z++) {
        if (arr[x] + arr[y] + arr[z] == sum) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (found) {
    console.log("found");
  } else {
    console.log("not found");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it can. please add the code you have.

Comment: @Justcode, now is it correct?

Comment: @AyushSharma not a negative voter, but adding more description would help.

Comment: Need help, @NinaScholz

Comment: Perhaps code review?

Comment: @mplungjan Not sure if it has enough context for that. OP should definitely read [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table and one loop for the array and one for the sum of two items.

```js
function find(array, sum) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    return array.some((v, i, a) => {
        a.slice(0, i).forEach(w => hash[v + w] = true);
        return hash[sum - v];
    });
}

console.log(find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 8));
console.log(find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 42));
```

If you like it more functional with a closure over a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the sum two values, then this would work, too.

```js
function find(array, sum) {
    return array.some(
        (s => (v, i, a) => a.slice(0, i).reduce((t, w) => t.add(v + w), s).has(sum - v))
        (new Set)
    );
}

console.log(find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 8));
console.log(find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 42));
```